# How to add objects to a private list with a method?

Tags: c#, list, object, addition, private

You can see the list i created is private and I want to be able to add objects to the list aswell as showing the user the list through methods AddBook() and ShowBooks().

```
public class Library
{
    private List<Book> Books = new List<Book>();       

    public static void AddBook()
    {
    }

    public static void ShowBooks()
    {
        foreach (Book item in Books)  
        //This foreach-loop doesn't work since its a private list.
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Books found");
        }
    }
}
```

The loop doesnt work since "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property" refering to the list.

Comment: The `Books` variable is not static.You should take a look at [this thread about `static`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413898/what-does-the-static-keyword-do-in-a-class)

Comment: why would you make the methods static?

Comment: what is the purpose of this code? how do you plan to use it? what's the purpose of the private list? please explain clearly what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to use static on the books collection do this:

```
public class Library
{
    private List<Book> Books = new List<Book>();       

    public void AddBook()
    {
    }

    public void ShowBooks()
    {
        var library = new Library();
        foreach (Book item in Books)  
        {
            //This foreach-loop doesn't work since its a private list.
            library.Books.Add(item);
            Console.WriteLine("Books found");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use static methods you can try this

```
using System;
```

using System.Collections.Generic;

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        Library.AddBook(new Book(){name = "test"});
        Library.AddBook(new Book(){name = "test1"});

        Library.ShowBooks();
    }
}

public class Book
{
    public string name;
}

public static class Library
{
    private static List<Book> Books = new List<Book>();

    public static void AddBook(Book b1)
    {
        Books.Add(b1);
    }

    public static void ShowBooks()
    {
        foreach (Book item in Books)  
        //This foreach-loop doesn't work since its a private list.
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.name);
        }
    }
}
```

without static methods you can try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;


public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Library l1 = new Library();
        l1.AddBook(new Book(){name = "test"});
        l1.AddBook(new Book(){name = "test1"});

        l1.ShowBooks();
    }
}


public class Book
{
    public string name;
}

public  class Library
{
    private  List<Book> Books = new List<Book>();

    public  void AddBook(Book b1)
    {
        Books.Add(b1);
    }

    public  void ShowBooks()
    {
        foreach (Book item in Books)  
        //This foreach-loop doesn't work since its a private list.
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.name);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that your List-instance is non-static, while your methods are. You either have to change your List to be static, or you methods to be non static. Following good OO Design, I would suggest you remove the static modifier from your methods. I also applied a readonly modifier to your List and changed It to be ICollection, as you do not seem to need indexed access. And also applied some common naming patterns.

```
public class Library
{
    private readonly ICollection<Book> _books = new List<Book>();       


    public void AddBook(Book book)
    {
        _books.Add(book);
    }

    public void ShowBooks()
    {
        foreach (Book item in _books)  
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Books found");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because from the authors code, the list is only created once `new List<Book>()`. Note that only the list is read only, not the items in the list. You can still add new items to the list. Otherwise you would expose it as an `IReadOnlyCollection<Book>`.